# Remove all but object with latest date property from arraylist in java

Tags: java, list, date, arraylist, filter

I have an arraylist with around 10.000 objects. Each of this objects have the following properties (and some more but not important):

Hostname (string)
Lastseen (Date)

This arraylist has to be filtered into a final list.

The arraylist can have multiple objects with the same hostname. If the hostname is the same then I only want the object in my final list which has the latest Lastseen date.

If there is only one occurrence of the hostname then it should also be in the final list no matter what the lastseen date is.

Edit: sorry for not providing code, see comment below

Comment: [where's your code?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sort the list by `lastseen (date)`, and remove all but the last entry.

Comment: Can be easily done by using a `Map<String, MyObj>`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions asking for (home)work help must include a summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty solving it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Sorry for not providing code. What i have tried so far is just get the first item. Then loop through all the other items and see if i find a match on hostname and if not add it to a new list. If i did find a match I add them to a new list, compare all the dates. Add the latest one to the temp list and remove all the others from the main list. Way to complex I understand but I don't know how to do it in a better way, that is why i came here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you use Java 8, it could be done with something like this:

```
List<MyClass> result = list.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        MyClass::getHostName,
        Collectors.toCollection(
            () -> new TreeSet<>((a, b) -> a.getLastSeen().compareTo(b.getLastSeen()))
        )
    )
).values().stream().map(TreeSet::last).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It first groups the values by hostname and collects the instances of `MyClass` with the same hostname into a `TreeSet`, then for each hostname it keeps only the instance with the latest date.

Comment: I am amazed, this does exactly what I needed. At first it gave an error but that was because in some occasions hostname was empty so I added a filter which removes items with no hostname (which I learned from another stackoverflow question). Thanks a lot! Next step for me is trying to understand what exactly your code is doing so next time I can use it in another occasion.

Comment: I describe my code at the end of my answer if not clear enough, just tell me, and I will try to improve

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I think I first need to learn on what exactly stream() and collect() does.